# How to populate generic array to main

Tags: java, arrays, object, generics

I've got a generic array class and I want to return an array in the main so I can use the sort method that I have ready in the main. I understand that the constructor has an array in it so I'm wondering if I can use that. Or do I need to set up a new method to return this.array ? Also it returns a generic array, how do I choose the type in main?

```
 public class dynamicArray <T>{

private int index;
private T[] array;

public dynamicArray() {

    array = (T[])new Object[10];
    this.index = 0;

}

public T [] populate() {
    return this.array;
}
```

Here I chose the integer type for the class. I'm not sure how can I extract the

array from the constructor.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     dynamicArray<Integer>array = new<Integer>dynamicArray();
     array.add(10);
     array.add(5);
     array.add(6);
     array.add(11);
     array.add(13);
     array.add(20);

     int [] arr = array.populate();
     mergeSort(arr);

     System.out.println(array.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ask two question :

1. How to set Integer type of that array object.
2. How to get Integer[] to int[]

Here is the code :

```
private int index;
private T[] array;

public dynamicArray() {

    array = (T[])new Object[10];
    this.index = 0;

}

public T [] populate() {
    return this.array;
}

public void add(T x) {
    array[++index] = x;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     dynamicArray<Integer>array = new<Integer>dynamicArray();
     array.add(10);
     array.add(5);
     array.add(6);
     array.add(11);
     array.add(13);
     array.add(20);

     int[] arr = Arrays.stream(array.populate())
                .mapToInt(i -> i)
                .toArray();
     System.out.println(array.toString());

}
```

Answer for 1st question is you can not set Integer type because there wasn't any add method in your class. Answer for 2nd question is you try to convert Integer[] to int[] but there is no direct way to cast this. you just need to change Integer -> Object then Object -> int. This can be done easily using streams which is in Java 8 and i have used lambda here for showing power of lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, arrays and generics don't work well together. Take a look at the [source code of java's ArrayList](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) - it is implemented with an `Object[]` and not a `T[]` - then every *method* will cast to T (which costs literally zero, it's just ugly and causes compiler warnings). I advise you do the same here: Arrays actually KNOW their component type (unlike a list of Ts, which does not, there is no method on a `java.util.List` that you can invoke to get the component type), and therefore casting `Object[]` to `T[]` is just wrong; java allows this solely for backwards compatibility reasons.

Basically, you can't work with `T[]` without things being subtly wrong and a lot of compiler errors.

In this specific case? I would strenuously advise you to use a `private List<T> array;` field instead of a `T[]` field.

Your call to `array.populate()` (that seems like a bizarre name for this method!) *IS* retrieving the array you created in the constructor. You are doing what you're asking for: "Extracting the array from the constructor" - invoking `populate()` on the object returned by the `new dynamicArray<Integer>()` is doing exactly that.

NB: You have a typo in your source code. it's `new dynamicArray<Integer>();`, not `new<Integer>dynamicArray();`. Perhaps that's causing some issues?

NB2: Java conventions dictate it's `DynamicArray`, and something like `getBackingArray` (instead of `populate`).

Comment: "arrays and java don't work well together." <- Did you mean to say Arrays and **Generics** don't work well together in java?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible alternative.  Pass the type of array to the constructor.  But essentially you are creating a limited form of `ArrayList` so you may just as well use that. Note that this still has the limitation that you can't use primitive arrays as the array type.

```
dynamicArray<Integer> array = new dynamicArray<>(new Integer[0]);

array.add(10);
array.add(5);
array.add(6);
array.add(11);
array.add(13);
array.add(20);

Integer[] a = array.getArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

}

class dynamicArray<T> {

    private int size = 0;
    private T[] array;

    public dynamicArray(T[] a) {
        array = a;
    }

    public void add(T value) {
        if (array.length == size) {
            array = Arrays.copyOf(array, size == 0 ? 10 : size*2);
        }
        array[size++] = value;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T[] getArray() {
        // need to copy the array since the length and size could be different.
        T[] arrayCopy = (T[]) Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, arrayCopy, 0, size);
        return arrayCopy;
    }
}
```